# C# WinForm - Change the Day Base on my following conditions. Loop issues

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a loan amortization schedule using my codes below

The logic is, when I have 1000 for principal value, 10 as the payment number(given, every term will be multiplied by 2 so it will be 20) and the payment that will cut the 1000 to 20 schedules.

```
decimal end_balance2 = 0;

var fromDate = date_from2.Value; // The sample date is 10/1/2015

decimal PV = 1000;
decimal TV = 10; // the loop will be x2 by the term value... so it will loop 20 instead
decimal PYMTS = 100;

String PV_string = Convert.ToString(PV);

decimal totalBalance = 0;

int count;

for (count = 0; count < TV; count++)
   {
    datagrid.Rows.Add(1);
    int numrows = count + 1;

    datagrid.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = numrows;

    datagrid.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value = PYMTS.ToString("##,###.00");

    PV = PV - PYMTS;

    if (fromDate.Day <= 5)
    {
       fromDate = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 5);
    }
    else if (fromDate.Day <= 10)
    {
       fromDate = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 10);
    }
    else if (fromDate.Day <= 15)
    {
       fromDate = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 15);
    }
    else if (fromDate.Day <= 20)
    {
       fromDate = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 20);
    }
    else if (fromDate.Day <= 25)
    {
       fromDate = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 25);
    }
    else
    {
       fromDate = new DateTime(fromDate.Year, fromDate.Month, 30);
    }

    fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(30);// Increment by 30 for every loop

    datagrid.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate.ToShortDateString();
 }
 end_balance2 = datagrid.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();    
 datagrid.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = PV_string;
```

The logic of the date below is, when I choose the datetimepicker the day, e.g the day is less than or equal to 5, it will show the day as fix as 5 only. The same approach to other day.

The problem is, I don't know why the date on the first 10 loop is correct and the second 10 loop is wrong. See the image below...
[image]
Please help me to fix the day only. I'm done with the other codes but I'm get stuck with this issue. Thanks in advance! Please drop your answers/comments below.

Comment: Unless you can modify your question, it will probably be closed because "why is this code not working" questions are specifically off-topic.  Please read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To follow up on @roryap's comment, it's not that those questions are offtopic, but questions that are asking for help on why code isn't working _"must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."_ IE ideally it will be a minimal repro that others can take and compile themselves to see/debug the behaviour.

Comment: Well the question did provide the desired behavior.  Given that the OP wasn't sure what was causing the issue, it could not be *significantly* shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assume that you can move a month forward by adding 30 days

> fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(30);// Increment by 30 for every loop

That is not the case, as some months have 28, 29 or 31 days.

Use [DateTime.AddMonths(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Sir, can you explain this further? :)

Comment: @mark -- I think it's pretty clear.  Not all months have 30 days.

Comment: @mark What are you confused about? He quoted your 'bad' line of code, said why it doesn't work (different months have different amount of days), **and** suggested what code (and argument) to use instead. Actually you really can't ask for a more thorough answer, as brief as it might be.

Comment: What date to you get if you start with 1/31 and add 30 days?  Hint: You miss February entirely.

Comment: Yeah, I know. @roryap but why the code from 1-10 executed the right date even though they haven't exact 30 day? Right? My concern is, why starting 11-20, the date is wrong...

Comment: @mark: You don't state the initial value of `fromDate` in your question, though we can deduce a range since you print out 1..5 since you print out 5 on the first line.  Without the initial value I can't do the specific math for you.  However, you can easily do that yourself.

Comment: @EricJ. I edited my code. Please see the "fromDate" value.

Comment: Step through in the debugger and you will see for yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I already debug those stuff but I can't find the clue to fix it. :(